# Button squashed in a table layout panel

Tags: c#, winforms, button

i have added a button to a table layout panel programatically, and whilst it seems to be resizing in terms of width, the height of it seems to be very squashed, so much so you cant make out any of the text.

I was wondering if anyone new why this might be?

Thanks

for reference i have the buttons autosize property to true in hope they would resize but they dont :/

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? And relevant code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to make sure the row that your button is being added to is set to `AutoSize`.

If you want to do it programatically:

```
tableLayoutPanel.RowStyles[n].SizeType = SizeType.AutoSize;
```

Where n is the zero-based index of the row.